# How to pass ElasticSearch query to hadoop

Tags: sql, hadoop, elasticsearch, presto

I am working on a project to allow searching on Hadoop. How it works is the query is first passed to ES, then the resulting IDs are passed back to SQL, like so:

```
SELECT ... WHERE id in [1,24,383,2912,...]
```

This works well when we have 100 or 1000 ids to pass back to SQL-on-Hadoop, but not so well if we have 100K or 1M+ ids to pass back. What are some alternative approaches to pass the result set (list of ids?) from ES back to SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert all **elastic search** ids in to a separate table then join it with source table.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE ELASTIC_SEARCH_ID(id INT);

SELECT ... FROM SOURCE S JOIN ELASTIC_SEARCH_ID ES ON S.ID=ES.ID;
```

Comment: Thanks -- any other approaches, as doing a join would be pretty inefficient (if there's a more performant alternative) ?

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer and I asked a follow-up here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125754/passing-reduced-es-query-results-to-sql?noredirect=1&lq=1.